# How to wait for particular time in script at anywhere?

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, automation, webdriver

I am trying to wait for certain time but before loading the page exception is thrown. Please tell me how to wait Explicitly in a page.
Scenario is- When homepage is loading then loader is loading for 5-6 sec. Here I want to wait upto loader is not disable.

Base class-->

```
 package BasePOI;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;

import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver;

public class Setup {

    public  static WebDriver driver;
    By counselor=By.id("counselor_login");
    public  void Websiteopen() 
    {

        driver = new FirefoxDriver();
        driver.manage().window().maximize();
        driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(20, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
        driver.get("url");
    }

    public Setup(WebDriver driver)
    {

        this.driver=driver;
    }
    public Setup()
    {
    }
    public WebDriver getDriver()
    {
        return this.driver;
    }

    public void click_Login_counselor()
    {
        driver.findElement(counselor).click();
    }
}
```

LoginPOI class--->

```
package BasePOI;

import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;

import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.ExpectedConditions;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.WebDriverWait;

public class LoginPOI {
    public WebDriver driver;

    // home
    By home_login = By.linkText("Login");
    By about_us = By.linkText("About Us");

    // login
    By counselor = By.id("counselor_login");
    By user = By.id("user_login");
    By username = By.id("username");
    By password = By.id("password");
    By Login = By.name("Login");
    By create_account = By.name("Login");

    By Logout = By.linkText("Logout");
    By Loader=By.id("loader");

    public void click_Login_button() {

        this.driver = new Setup().getDriver();
        //driver.manage().timeouts().pageLoadTimeout(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
        driver.findElement(home_login).click();

    }

    public void click_Login_counselor() {
        driver.findElement(counselor).click();
    }

    public void click_Login_user() {
        driver.findElement(user).click();
    }

    public void Enter_login_data(String uname, String pwd) {
        driver.findElement(username).clear();
        driver.findElement(username).sendKeys(uname);
        driver.findElement(password).clear();
        driver.findElement(password).sendKeys(pwd);
    }

    public void click_Login() {
        driver.findElement(Login).click();
    }

    public void waitforLogin(){
        System.out.println("a");
        WebDriverWait wait=new WebDriverWait(driver,15);
        WebElement b=wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(Login));
        System.out.println(b);

    }
}
```

Login class-->

```
package Functionlity;

import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.testng.annotations.Test;
import BasePOI.LoginPOI;
import BasePOI.Setup;

public class Login  
{
    public WebDriver driver;

    @Test
    public void openwebsite() throws InterruptedException {
        Setup a = new Setup(driver);
        LoginPOI b = new LoginPOI();

        a.Websiteopen();

        b.waitforLogin();

        b.click_Login_button();



        b.click_Login_user();

        a.click_Login_counselor();

    }
}
```

error--->

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.google.common.base.Preconditions.checkNotNull(Preconditions.java:212)
    at org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.FluentWait.<init>(FluentWait.java:102)
    at org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.WebDriverWait.<init>(WebDriverWait.java:71)
    at org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.WebDriverWait.<init>(WebDriverWait.java:45)
    at BasePOI.LoginPOI.waitforLogin(LoginPOI.java:58)
    at Functionlity.Login.openwebsite(Login.java:20)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.testng.internal.MethodInvocationHelper.invokeMethod(MethodInvocationHelper.java:86)
    at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeMethod(Invoker.java:643)
    at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeTestMethod(Invoker.java:820)
    at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeTestMethods(Invoker.java:1128)
    at org.testng.internal.TestMethodWorker.invokeTestMethods(TestMethodWorker.java:129)
    at org.testng.internal.TestMethodWorker.run(TestMethodWorker.java:112)
    at org.testng.TestRunner.privateRun(TestRunner.java:782)
    at org.testng.TestRunner.run(TestRunner.java:632)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.runTest(SuiteRunner.java:366)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.runSequentially(SuiteRunner.java:361)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.privateRun(SuiteRunner.java:319)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.run(SuiteRunner.java:268)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.runSuite(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:52)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.run(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:86)
    at org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesSequentially(TestNG.java:1244)
    at org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesLocally(TestNG.java:1169)
    at org.testng.TestNG.run(TestNG.java:1064)
    at org.testng.remote.RemoteTestNG.run(RemoteTestNG.java:113)
    at org.testng.remote.RemoteTestNG.initAndRun(RemoteTestNG.java:206)
    at org.testng.remote.RemoteTestNG.main(RemoteTestNG.java:177)
```

Before execute click login button , I want to wait upto pageloader is not disable

Comment: Can you remove unnecessary lines of code and leave just those that could cause the issue? Also provide with `HTML` code for "pageloader"

Comment: <div id="loader" style="display: none;"/>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try below code to wait until "pageloader" disappeared:

```
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 10);
wait.until(ExpectedConditions.presenceOfElementLocated(By.id('loader')));
wait.until(ExpectedConditions.invisibilityOfElementLocated(By.id('loader')));
```

Comment: java.lang.NullPointerException
 at com.google.common.base.Preconditions.checkNotNull(Preconditions.java:212)

Comment: Could you put `WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 10);` in the same place where `driver` is initialized?

Comment: sorry andersson, i am not initilized driver in that method. Now problem is solved. Thanks